# member functions with same name C++

Tags: c++, function, class

I found an example where in the a class definition, there were 2 member functions defined, but with the same name and same number of arguments:

```
const MyClass& operator [] (int index) const;
MyClass& operator [] (int index);
```

My question is how will the compiler know which operator definition it needs to use?

Comment: See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading). It explains this precise scenario.

Comment: They differ in the `const` qualifier though...

Comment: Next time can you ask, because I don't see your question :)

Comment: This is a non-question.  What are you trying to ask?  const qualifiers matter in function and type signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two methods differ only in the declaration of `const`, the const version will be selected if it is called from a pointer or reference that is also declared `const`. Otherwise you will get the non-const version.

This is most commonly seen in the implementation of `vector`. If you have a const vector, you don't want to be able to change any of the elements, so a const reference to an element is returned.

Answer (score 1):

They are different methods, primarily due to the `const` suffix.

The return value (alone) cannot be used to resolve overloaded methods or operators.

**Edit 1:**
You understanding is not correct.

The first function returns a *reference*, which cannot be modified, to an object.  It does not return a copy. The method is not allowed to modify class members.

The second function returns a *reference* to an object, the object can be modified.  The method is allowed to modify class members.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to use the operator in a constant function, the constant operator will be called, otherwise, the non-constant one will be called. This is a subtlety that often trips people up as if you only define the non-constant operator but attempt to use it in a constant function it will result in errors.